# rxjs shareReplay with refCount off doesn't subscribe to the source until the first downstream subscriber

Tags: angular, rxjs

```js
export class DataService {
  private readonly dataSubject: Subject<Data> = new Subject();

  public readonly myData$: Observable<Data>;

  constructor() {
    this.myData$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      shareReplay({
        bufferSize: 1,
        refCount: false,
      }),
    );
    // this would solve the problem, but is an ugly workaround
    // this.myData$.subscribe();
  }

  update(data: Data) {
    this.dataSubject.next(data);
  }
```

There's this global singleton `DataService`, which should provide a certain data to various parts of the application. When the consumers subscribe, they should immediately receive the last value, and the new ones in the future.

My understanding was the following: if I add the `shareReplay` as shown above, with `refCount`ing turned off, it will subscribe to its upstream observable (ie. the `dataSubject` in this case) *immediately* and keep the last value, and when there are downstream subscribers, emit the last value and also any future ones.

What happens instead, if I understand correctly: if the first downstream subscriber comes later than the first value in source the subject, than the first value is lost, because at that point the `shareReplay` was not subscribed to the subject, so it didn't collect the previous value. If I immediately add a downstream subscriber, that fixes the problem, but that's a bit ugly.

I was able to solve my issue with the workaround below which is a bit nicer, where I moved the replay functionality into the subject itself, so that it already keeps the last values regardless of the subscribers. But still would like to know what I might be missing how the `shareReplay` works, or if I made a mistake in the code above.

```js
export class DataService {
  private readonly dataSubject: Subject<Data> = new ReplaySubject();

  public readonly myData$: Observable<Data>;

  constructor() {
    this.myData$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      share(),
    );
  }

  update(data: Data) {
    this.dataSubject.next(data);
  }
```

Comment: could you try to remove `.asObservable()`? I think the value is lost there

Comment: Why don't you use a behaviorSubject? it emits the current value to any new subscribers : https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

Comment: @QuentinFonck because I don't want to specify an initial value, because any value would be wrong. Also, if you look at my 2nd code snippet, I ended up solving the issue with `ReplaySubject`, but the question was what is wrong with `shareReplay` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `Subject`, if the `next` happens before a `subscribe`, then the value is lost. So new subscribers can't get the last value. Therefore it's recommended to use a `ReplaySubject` or a `BehaviorSubject` instead to avoid losing values like this.

To answer the actual question, as explained in [this article](https://itnext.io/the-magic-of-rxjs-sharing-operators-and-their-differences-3a03d699d255) about `shareReplay`:

> refCount: false means that upon first subscription to ReplaySubject it will subscribe to Source

No, it will not subscribe immediately.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the question is about `shareReplay`. Shouldn't that subscribe immediately when used with `refCount: false`?

Comment: @AlexBiro I don't know what is actually subscribing to `this.myData$` but the subscription will happen when `.subscribe` is called on it, no sooner. Maybe this article can help you understand https://itnext.io/the-magic-of-rxjs-sharing-operators-and-their-differences-3a03d699d255, see the "shareReplay() without refCount" bit.

Comment: ahaaa, that was probably the key, from the linked article: _refCount: false means that upon first subscription to ReplaySubject it will subscribe to Source._ So `shareReplay` will not subscribe to the upstream observable until the first downstream subscriber, even with `refCount: false`. Can you please add that to your answer? I would accept it with that.